# How can I implement different modal forms on the same page?

Tags: reactjs

I am building a navigation bar where a different modal form will pop up as I click an item on the navbar.

I want to know how I should go about to implement this because I tried but the same form always show up as I clicked on different navigation link.

For example, as I click 'Add a pic', I want a modal form to with image title and url to show up. If I click 'Signup' I want a modal form with name, password, email to show up, etc. How can I construct the 'isOpen' state the right way?

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {NavBar} from './components/navbar.js';
import {AddPicModal} from './components/addPicModal.js';
import {SignUpForm} from './components/signupForm.js'
import './App.css';


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state ={isOpen: false};

  }

  showModal = () => {
    this.setState({ isOpen: true });
  };

  hideModal = () => {
    this.setState({ isOpen: false });
  };
  render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">
      <NavBar showModal={this.showModal}/>

      <AddPicModal
                isOpen={this.state.isOpen}
                onClose={this.hideModal}/>


      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**AddPicModal.js**

```
import React , {Component} from 'react';

import {Modal,Form, FormControl, FormGroup, ControlLabel, HelpBlock, Button} from 'react-bootstrap/lib';


function FieldGroup({ id, label, help, ...props }) {
  return (
    <FormGroup controlId={id}>
      <ControlLabel>{label}</ControlLabel>
      <FormControl {...props} />
      {help && <HelpBlock>{help}</HelpBlock>}
    </FormGroup>
  );
}
export class AddPicModal extends Component{


    render(){
        console.log(this.props.isOpen);
        if(!this.props.isOpen){
            return null;
        }
        return(
            <div className="static-modal">
                <Modal.Dialog>
                    <Modal.Header>
                        <Modal.Title>Add New Picture</Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>

                    <Modal.Body>
                        <Form>
                            <FieldGroup
                                id="name"
                                type="text"
                                placeholder="Enter a title"/>
                            <FieldGroup
                                id="url"
                                type="text"
                                placeholder="Enter a URL"
                            />


                        </Form>
                    </Modal.Body>

                    <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button onClick={this.props.onClose}>Close</Button>
                    <Button  bsStyle="primary">Add</Button>
                    </Modal.Footer>
                </Modal.Dialog>
            </div>
            );
    }


}
```

**NavBar.js**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
 import {NavItem, Nav, Navbar} from 'react-bootstrap/lib';

 export class NavBar extends Component{

     render(){

         return(
             <Navbar inverse collapseOnSelect>
            <Navbar.Header>
                <Navbar.Brand>
                  <a href="#brand">Pinterest</a>
                </Navbar.Brand>
                <Navbar.Toggle />
             </Navbar.Header>
    <Navbar.Collapse>
    <Nav>
      <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">
        Home
      </NavItem>
      <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">
        My Wall
      </NavItem>
      <NavItem eventKey={3} href="#" onClick={this.props.showModal}>
      Add New Picture
      </NavItem>
    </Nav>
    <Nav pullRight>
      <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#" >
        Login
      </NavItem>
      <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">
        Signup
      </NavItem>
    </Nav>
  </Navbar.Collapse>
</Navbar>
             )
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem a couple of months ago.

what I did was I created 3 methods for the different forms that I wanted to show. First, i set state to each one that got initialized to true when I wanted the forms to show in my render method. I'm passing the state of what to show in my forms to my components and then I'm calling them to props and then I'm checking if they're true or not to which they render the different forms.

```js
import React from 'react';

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Modal, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

import Login from '../components/Login';
import Register from '../components/Register';
import Forgotpassword from '../components/Forgotpassword';

class Header extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
        this.handleShow = this.handleShow.bind(this);

        this.showLogin = this.showLogin.bind(this);
        this.showRegister = this.showRegister.bind(this);
        this.showforgotPassword = this.showforgotPassword.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            show: false,
            showLogin: true,
            showRegister: false,
            showforgotPassword: false,
            isloggedIn: false,
            isIdle: false,
        }
    }

    handleClose(){
        this.setState({
            show:false,
            // When user closes modal, set screen back to login
            showLogin: true,
            showRegister: false,
            showforgotPassword: false,
        });
    }

    handleShow(){
        this.setState({
            show:true
        });
    }

    showLogin(){
        this.setState({
            showLogin: true,
            showRegister: false,
            showforgotPassword: false,
        })
    }

    showRegister(){
        this.setState({
            showLogin: false,
            showRegister: true,
            showforgotPassword: false,
        })
    }

    showforgotPassword(){
        this.setState({
            showLogin: false,
            showRegister: false,
            showforgotPassword: true,
        })
    }

    render(){
        const formState = [this.state.showLogin, this.state.showRegister, this.state.showforgotPassword];
        let showForm = null;

        if(formState[0] === true) {
            showForm = <Login showRegister={this.showRegister} showforgotPassword={this.showforgotPassword} />
        } else if(formState[1] === true) {
            showForm = <Register showLogin={this.showLogin} />
        } else if(formState[2] === true) {
            showForm = <Forgotpassword showLogin={this.showLogin} />
        }

        // console.log(this.state);

        return (
            <div className="header-container">
                <nav className="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
                    <Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.handleClose}>
                        <Modal.Body>
                            {showForm}
                        </Modal.Body>
                    </Modal>
                </nav>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Header;
```